# How to add right padding to a menu in python

Tags: python, menu, padding

I need to add right padding to my menu this is my code

```
menu_options = {
1: 'Option 1',
2: 'Option 2',
3: 'Option 3',
4: 'Exit',
```

}

```
def print_menu():
for key in menu_options.keys():
    print (key, '.', menu_options[key])
```

Comment: Calculate the longest string for each column, then use .rjust(length) to fill each column with enough spaces to make them all the same length.

Comment: @ArtieVandelay please avoid answering questions in the comment section

Comment: @blankettripod I apologize, I figured since I didn't provide any specific code, it wasn't technically an answer but just a starting point.